# Inserting an iframe in a Visual Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, automation, iframe, visual-flows

Has anyone ever experimented or successfully included an iframe inside of a visual flow? I understand there is some HTML you can experiment with in the TextArea resource but I have not had any luck with getting it to stay after embed this for example:

`<iframe src="https://www.google.com"></iframe>`

Any suggestions at how I could go about this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iframes have been disabled in Salesforce since 2015 to prevent clickjack.

Please see resource here:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=IFRAME-or-Web-Tab-Content-Displays-Blank-Page-1327107637323&type=1